# Upgrading spring boot from 1.5.x to 2.0.x and getting error for @Component and @Scope annotations

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

After upgrading spring boot version from 1.5.x to 2.0.x, I have started getting errors for `@Component` and `@Scope` annotations. I searched a lot but couldn't find anything about these moving to different packages or something. can somebody help ?
Specific error message is as below :

```
package org.springframework.stereotype does not exist
package org.springframework.context.annotation does not exist
```

Comment: do `maven` clean build or gradle clean build

Comment: Both Component and Scope classes are still in the same package in Spring 2.0.x also. Looks some problem with your build. Please check if it is able to download the dependencies for Spring 2.0.x.

Comment: had to add dependency on spring-context in my pom.xml explicitly. previously I just had spring-web in my pom.